# broken animate() algorithm in portfolio list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html

```
<ul class="wrap">
    <li title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"></li>
    <li title="consectetur adipisicing elit"></li>
    <li title="incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"></li>
    <li title="Ut enim ad minim veniam"></li>
    <li title="quis nostrud exercitation ullamco"></li>
    <li title="laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo"></li>
    <li title="Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit"></li>
    <li title=" Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non"></li>
    <div class="sub">
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}

body{
    padding: 100px;
}


ul{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

li{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.sub{
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    background: #ff3030;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var li = $('.wrap').children('li'),
    sub = $('.sub');

li.on('mouseover', function() {
    sub.show();
    var left = $(this).offset().left,
        top = $(this).offset().top,
        text = $(this).attr('title'),
        bg = $('.bg');
    sub.stop().animate({
        left: left - $('.wrap').offset().left,
        top: top - $('.wrap').offset().top 
    });
    bg.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, function() {
        bg.text(text);
        bg.animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    sub.fadeOut();
});
```

This is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/GTHM4/

And it better looks in full width
http://jsfiddle.net/GTHM4/embedded/result/

As you can see problem is in "broken" work 'mouseleave' event, and the div "bg" always 'wants' go away... What's wrong?

Comment: It's only a suggestion but you have noticed that when you get the hover event on the li element the div element appers on the top and that means that the hover event of li disapear and start the mouseleave event, then div dissapears and again hover event and that's infinite, you must control when you really want to have that events.

Comment: What exactly is  the desired effect? is the red div supposed to blink?

Comment: Maybe, I will work on it more, thanx for help and advises. Tilwin Joy, the desired effect is appending bg on li, and hiding of this bg, when cursor is out from li.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine

```
var li = $('.wrap').children('li'),
            sub = $('.sub'),
    wrap = $('.wrap');

        wrap.on('mouseover','li', function() {
            sub.show();
            var left = $(this).offset().left,
                top = $(this).offset().top,
                text = $(this).attr('title'),
                bg = $('.bg');
            sub.stop().animate({
                left: left - $('.wrap').offset().left,
                top: top - $('.wrap').offset().top 
            });
            bg.stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, function() {
                bg.text(text);
                bg.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            });
        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
            sub.fadeOut();
        });
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/fazalrasel/GTHM4/1/

Comment: sorry, but there is a depend from wrap, but bg should fadeout when cursor is out from li, but not wrap.

Comment: Could you please make it clear what actually you want? Its very hard to understand you English. You said that the bg always wants to go... You can fix it by event delegation that I suggested... What do you mean by **bg should fadeout when cursor is out from li, but not wrap**